# I am having trouble starting how to show the difference operator $\Delta $ is linear for a sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

I am trying to show that the difference operator $\Delta$ is linear, for a sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that: $$ \Delta (a_n + b_n) = \Delta a_n + \Delta b_n $$ The way we have defined $\Delta a_n$ is the following: $$\Delta a_n = b_n \\ \Rightarrow \Delta a_n = a_n - a_{n-1} $$ This is where I am having trouble showing this. Also then from this formula I have to find some formula for:
$$ \Delta^4 a_n $$ but I don't now how this property above would help me in finding that formula. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So your question is : find a formula for $\Delta^4 n$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the linearity, you have

$$\Delta(a_n+b_n) = (a_n+b_n)-(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}) $$

$$= (a_n-a_{n-1})+(b_n-b_{n-1})= \Delta a_n + \Delta b_n. $$

Concerning the second part, you have

$$ \Delta^2 a_n = \Delta(\Delta a_n)= \Delta(a_n-a_{n-1})= \Delta a_n- \Delta a_{n-1}= a_n -2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}. $$

Can you finish from here?